# In C++ How can I read in different types of data in one instream of the same cin object

Tags: c++

I wrote a custom class `CMyistream_iterator`. Its constructor has an argument of an `istream` object.

```
template <class T>
class CMyistream_iterator
{

private:
    T valArray[100];
    int pos;
public:
    CMyistream_iterator(istream& in):pos(0){
        T n;
        int i=0;
        while(in>>n){
            *(valArray+i) = n;
            ++i;
        }      
    }
    T operator*();
};
```

But I meet some problems when I enter the data.

```
 int main(){
       CMyistream_iterator<int> inputInt(cin);
       //...somecode...           
       CMyistream_iterator<string> inputStr(cin);
       //...somecode...
    }
```

Data is entered like this:

> 22 33 44 tom jack+'\n'

The second class can't be constructed as it can't read in the next two strings.

It seems that when the integer iterator comes to the character 't', it was converted into EOF.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I do not see any storage for `valArray`.

Comment: Indeed. `valArray` is uninitialized.

Comment: Also, the body of your while loop could just be: `valArray[i++] = n;`

Comment: Your stream iterators both persistently read one type from `cin` (not the argument `in` you supply) until an error occurs.   In other words, they ASSUME all input is of the one type.   You can address the "problem" by using some other approach, such as interpreting input (i.e. parsing) to determine what the type is, rather than simply assuming it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that when the integer iterator comes to the character 't', it was converted into EOF.

That is not what happens. When `cin >> n` in the `int` iterator encounters the character `'t'`, it fails to read in an `int` value, and thus puts `cin` into an error state that you need to explicitly reset with `cin.clear()` before you can continue reading from `cin`.

Also, your iterator is not allocating memory for `valArray` to point at. You should consider using `std::vector` and let it manage the memory for you.